# Locking cells with App scripts in Google Sheets instead of data validation or hide all hints

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

i have a sheet where i have a column with a date and two columns (not side by side) where a user can insert data:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      A              |     C            |     H            |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      16.04.19       |     34           |     53           |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      17.04.19       |     40           |     23           |
```

and so on.

In the moment i use data validation where i check the date in A with the current date and then lock all cells of C and H (seperate validation) where A is not the current date. This works. The Problem is, that all data entered before (with the correct date) gets a hint with invalid data validation because the date is not like today. For the whole month these are many notificaitons.

Is there any way to either not show/deactivate these notifications in the cells or to do the same thing on another, better way, maybe with a script?

I am not familar with that, so i did not find a solution here, to achieve the same.

Thank you for your interest and helping ideas

Ruven

Comment: Would you like to remove validation on past dates?

Comment: Yes and no. When i change this, then past data can be changed, should be not.